# In the CoreNLP pipeline, is it possible to use the Coref tool (dcoref) with the new dependency parser tool (depparse)?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

This is how you would normally initialize a pipeline to run on some text:

```
//stanford NLP
static Properties props = new Properties();
static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;    
static void initStanfordPipeline() {
    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref"); // depparse is an option for using a new dependency parsing model
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
}
```

I get the following error when I try 'depparse' instead of 'parse' as an option in the pipeline:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "dcoref" requires annotator "parse"
```

Comment: This question makes complete sense to anyone familiar with stanford-nlp.  Please open, it really is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! This currently isn't possible in the pipeline, though it really ought to be. I'll bring it up in our next development meeting.

For now, if you know that your pipeline doesn't require constituency parses, you can easily get around this by setting a property in the pipeline flags: `-enforceRequirements false`.

However, it looks like you're using `dcoref`, which does require constituency parses --- so there's no way around using the `parse` annotator, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also using the coreference part of the tool. Would that still work?

Comment: Ah, I missed this earlier. No, it's not possible AFAIK to get away running coref without constituency parses. Updated my response.